# cannot using internet in VMWare

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation

I am using VMware Workstation version 7 on Ubuntu 10.10. I installed Windows XP service pack 3 for guest os. Within VMWare, I am using bridge connection that I assigned static IP address to be able to ping host IP address but I cannot ping default router gateway. I also tried to command "/etc/init.d/vmware start" on terminal. All tasks are able to start successfully except "VM communication interface socket family" I am not sure that how to setup network for my VMWare by using wireless.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you are having a DHCP server on your host computers network (like DSL router), then you should configure your VM for DHCP. In general when using bridged networking, configure your VM just like your host computer.

If you have more then one network conntroller in your host computer, you need to make sure, you bridged your VM to the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Is VMWare setup in bridged mode? I think it uses NAT mode by default. Try setting the gateway to the host IP address (the virtual one that is).